# Testflight web HTML environment for testers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, testflight

I am trying to create a test environment with testflight to test apps without having to enter ItunnesConnect .

I want to know if I can get the links of each version of an app to create an HTML file on my Web server with a list of links to each version .

I want to know whether there would also be done with internal or external testers. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, Apple does not provide this. Apps can only be installed via the TestFlight app with a valid Apple ID. If you do want to host it on your own web server you will need to have the all of the  device UDID in your Ad-Hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: i found this http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution

Comment: Yes, but that requires you to have the all the UDID of the devices on which you want to install the app on in the provisioning profile. And with this profile you will need to build your Ad-Hoc app.

Comment: ok I understand, I will try this because I don`t need too much devices. Thank you for you comments